# How to set multiple View's in viewpager?

Tags: android, android-viewpager

recently i came across viewpager but one of its main cons is we cannot set mutiple view in viewpager , so i plan to make three layout in a screen manipulate it according to the size but it is getting crashed IndexOutOfBound exception , so am very much struggling with this now let me explain what my requirement is i need three view in per page , suppose if i list of size 5 i need three in first page and two in next like this i want , now let me post what i have tried so far

This is the PagerAdapter am working with:

```
public class SummaryViewPagerAdapter extends PagerAdapter {

    private List<SummaryModel>mSummarymodelist;
    private Context context;
    private LayoutInflater inflater;


    public SummaryViewPagerAdapter(Context context, List<SummaryModel> summaryModels ) {
          this.mSummarymodelist=summaryModels;
          this.context=context;
      }



    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        int count=(mSummarymodelist.size()+3-1)/3;
        return count;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isViewFromObject(View view, Object object) {
         return view == object;
    }
    private void populateTextView(TextView status_txt,TextView status_count,  String status, String color, RelativeLayout layout,String count) {

        status_txt.setText(status);
        status_count.setText(count);
        layout.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor(color));
    }

    @Override
    public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup container, int position) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        inflater = (LayoutInflater) context
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        View itemView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.summary_viewholder,
                container, false);
        TextView status_txt= itemView.findViewById(R.id.txt_1);
        TextView count_txt=itemView.findViewById(R.id.count_1);
        RelativeLayout relativeLayout=itemView.findViewById(R.id.rl_1);
        position=position * 2;
        if (position <getRealCount()) {
            populateTextView(status_txt,count_txt,mSummarymodelist.get(position).getName(),mSummarymodelist.get(position).getColorCode(),relativeLayout, String.valueOf(mSummarymodelist.get(position).getCount()));
            status_txt.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            count_txt.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            relativeLayout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

        }
        else if(position==getRealCount()) {
            populateTextView(status_txt,count_txt,mSummarymodelist.get(position-1).getName(),mSummarymodelist.get(position-1).getColorCode(),relativeLayout, String.valueOf(mSummarymodelist.get(position-1).getCount()));
            status_txt.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            count_txt.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            relativeLayout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

        }
        else {
            status_txt.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            count_txt.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            relativeLayout.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

        }
        position++;
        status_txt= itemView.findViewById(R.id.txt_2);
        count_txt=itemView.findViewById(R.id.count_2);
        relativeLayout=itemView.findViewById(R.id.rl_2);
        if (position < getRealCount()) {
            populateTextView(status_txt,count_txt, mSummarymodelist.get(position).getName(),mSummarymodelist.get(position).getColorCode(),relativeLayout, String.valueOf(mSummarymodelist.get(position).getCount()));
            status_txt.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            count_txt.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            relativeLayout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }
        else if(position==getRealCount()) {
            populateTextView(status_txt,count_txt,mSummarymodelist.get(position-2).getName(),mSummarymodelist.get(position-2).getColorCode(),relativeLayout, String.valueOf(mSummarymodelist.get(position-2).getCount()));
            status_txt.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            count_txt.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            relativeLayout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

        }
        else {
            status_txt.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            count_txt.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            relativeLayout.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        }
        position++;
        status_txt= itemView.findViewById(R.id.txt_3);
        count_txt=itemView.findViewById(R.id.count_3);
        relativeLayout=itemView.findViewById(R.id.rl_3);
        if (position <getRealCount()) {
            populateTextView(status_txt,count_txt, mSummarymodelist.get(position).getName(),mSummarymodelist.get(position).getColorCode(),relativeLayout, String.valueOf(mSummarymodelist.get(position).getCount()));
            status_txt.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            count_txt.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            relativeLayout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }
        else if(position==getRealCount()) {
            populateTextView(status_txt,count_txt,mSummarymodelist.get(position-3).getName(),mSummarymodelist.get(position-3).getColorCode(),relativeLayout, String.valueOf(mSummarymodelist.get(position-3).getCount()));
            status_txt.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            count_txt.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            relativeLayout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

        }
        else {
            status_txt.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            count_txt.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            relativeLayout.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        }

       container.addView(itemView);
        return itemView;
    }

    @Override
    public void destroyItem(ViewGroup container, int position, Object object) {
        container.removeView((LinearLayout) object);
    }
    private int getRealCount() {
        return mSummarymodelist.size();
    }

}
```

But i couldn't achieve this like i want how to do this , Thanks in Advance !!

Comment: "we cannot set mutiple view in viewpager "? Where did you read this and What exactly you want to achieve ? Add some graphical representations .

Comment: yes i know we cannot set , but i need something like this https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/blob/master/ViewPager/MultiView2/app/src/main/java/com/commonsware/android/mvp2/MainActivity.java  what they have done with two view i need it make it with three

Comment: i need three view per page how can  i do this , please don't tell to reduce page width

Answer (score -1):

I don't get your `getCount()` method, have you tried to debug and see what it returns?
You could also try something like this

```
@Override
public int getCount() {
    return (int) Math.ceil(mSummarymodelist.size() / 3.f);
}
```

Comment: why i done like this  is if i get 1.5 round off to 2

Comment: @M.Yogeshwaran Sorry, I should use ``ceil()`` instead of ``round()``, I edited my post. Youd should post error log and tell us which line is causing it.